# Hidden Some field in .asp

Tags: sql, asp.net

Currently I have to hid a table that cannot view for some user. I'm very new in this .asp. I'm not sure how to do it in the coding as this coding not build by me.

As image below, i need to hid it from some user.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGi9b.jpg)

In this page, there have another table that can view by all user when they login and access to this page. Some one please me some idea. :)

Below the part of the table coding that i need to touch for me to hid it.

> Blockquote

Add Self-Collect DN
          
        
           
          
            
            
            " />
            
            "" then response.write "This DO-"&do2& " had been block!" end if%>
            
        
        
          DN-
          
            
          
        
        
          Saleman ID
          
            
          
        
        
          Customer Account

> Blockquote

Comment: Are you working in ancient ASP or ASPX (ASP.NET)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the table by assigning an `id`.

```
    <table id="IdHideShow" runat="server">
```

now in your code behind, you can manipulate the visibility of the table by the use of its `id` , depending on how you want it.

something like:

```
    If SomeBooleanConditionHere = True Then
       IdHideShow.Visible = True
    Else
       IdHideShow.Visible = False
    End If
```